# Seperating String Left side =, and Right side of =

Tags: java

i have a String , String a= "Geetha = GB"; now i want to save the value Geetha in B String, GB in C String. that is String B=Geetha  , String C=GB,(i.e  content left side the = in B,content Right side the = in C string ) 
without using index value

i.e  String B= a.substring(0, 5);

Please suggest me the answer..

Comment: `string.split("=");` will help you

Comment: Please look at split method in String class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive it by using this code

```
int iend = a.indexOf("="); 

if (iend != -1) 
{
    String B = a.substring(0 , iend);
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you, this is the answer i was expecting, but When i print B i get o/p "Geetha", to get "GB" what i should give in the String C=a.substring(????);

Comment: String C = a.substring( iend + 1, a.length() );

Answer (score 1):

Try `split()`. That will give you array of items split by "`\\s*=\\s*`"

```
String[] temp = tempString.split("\\s*=\\s*");

String B=temp[0];
String C=temp[1];
```

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  String a="Geetha=GB";
  String[] temp = a.split("=");
  for(String t:temp)
  {
   System.out.println(t);
  }

 }   when i use this code  i get the values "Geetha" and "GB" seperatly, but i wan to save this values in the variables B and C

Comment: you can accept my answer if it is working proper. So that other can use same.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a= "Geetha = GB";
String[] splitted = a.Split('=');
String b = splitted[0];
String c = splitted[1];
```